# Perl code to call variables hostname, portnumber into another variable

Tags: perl, perl-module

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use XML::Twig;
use HTTP::Request;

my @joblist = ('Testing','Integrity','TEST','Team_test','test','TEST_1','Update_Outlook');
my @score;

foreach my $job_name (@joblist) {
    my $url_a = 'http://myhost:8080/job/$job_name/api/xml';
    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
    $ua->timeout(10);
    $ua->env_proxy;
    my $response = $ua->get($url_a);
    if ($response->is_success) {
        my $content = $response->decoded_content;  # or whatever
        XML::Twig->new( twig_roots => { 'healthReport/score' => sub { push @score, $_->text; } }) ->parseurl($url_a);
        foreach my $var (@score) {
            print "$var \n";
        }
    }
    else {
        die $response->status_line;
    }
}
```

In above perl code I am calling $job_name into another variable $url_a.
But I'm getting following error.

```
404 Not Found at health.pl line 25.
```

Could someone please help me on this.Thanks.

Comment: This part seem pretty fine for me. So there is two possibilities: .1 error is located in some next lines (you may print more lines in your SO question) .2 your perl installation is not well completed or wrong.

Comment: @F.Hauri is correct. Your code works for me, too. Please [edit] your question and add the lines that come after it. Are you using `strict` and `warnings`?

Comment: Thanks @F.Hauri,. I have updated the question with full code.

Comment: Hmmm question have changed: `404 Not Found` mean: *At least on of constructed url not exist*:  Are you sure `http://myhost:8080/job/Integrity/api/xml` (for sample) is a valid URL?

Comment: Simply try to change `die $response->status_line;` by `printf STDERR "ERROR: %s\n", $response->status_line;` at line 25.

Comment: Yes The url [Link](http://myhost:8080/job/Integrity/api/xml) is correct.
Actually the error may be here :
my $url_a = 'http://myhost:8080/job/$job_name/api/xml';
$job_name is not substituting its value into $url_a.

Comment: Ok I've found your problem: At line 15: `$url_a=...` change quotes `'` by double quotes `"`!

Comment: I've posted this as an answer, so you could validate them, if they work;-)

Comment: I've rewrited line 15 in a more pretty manner, (using `join`) take a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this version:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use XML::Twig;
use HTTP::Request;

my @joblist = qw|Testing Integrity TEST Team_test test TEST_1 Update_Outlook|;
my @score;

foreach my $job_name (@joblist) {
    my $url_a = join("/","http://myhost:8080/job",$job_name,"api/xml");
    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
    $ua->timeout(10);
    $ua->env_proxy;
    my $response = $ua->get($url_a);
    if ($response->is_success) {
        my $content = $response->decoded_content;  # or whatever
        XML::Twig->new( twig_roots => { 'healthReport/score' => sub { push @score, $_->text; } }) ->parseurl($url_a);
        foreach my $var (@score) {
            print "$var \n";
        }
    }
    else {
        printf STDERR "ERROR job: %s, result: %s\n", 
        $job_name, $response->status_line;
    }
}
```